# Adding texture layer over stroke object (Grease Pencil)

Tags: texturing, grease-pencil, masking, layers

I add texture layer and I can clip texture to match underlying stroke object by clicking mask layer icon in the layer properties section.

There is an example in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeD0Fa53OQA).

I can do this in Blender 2.80 and 2.82 but can't make it work in 2.83 (and 2.90).

Images before and after masking are below.
Is this feature removed in 2.83 or am I missing something?

Before:

[image: Before applying mask]

After:

[image: After applying mask]

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Masks` section below layer list in 2.83 and later versions.

Adding new mask in here and clicking mask icon on the related layer solved the problem.

[image]